# admobのインタースティシャル広告を導入したい。

Tags: ios, swift, spritekit

SpriteKitを使って開発したゲームアプリにadmobのインタースティシャル広告を導入してみたのですが、動きません。SpriteKitを使わなければ広告が表示されます。 
Spritekitで実装する方法のアドバイスをいただければありがたいです。

frameworkなど必要なものは導入しております。

---

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, GameSceneDelegate , GADInterstitialDelegate{

    var interstitial: GADInterstitial = GADInterstitial()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadInterstitial()

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10.0,target:self,selector:Selector("gameOver"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    func gameOver() {

        print("call gameOver")
        self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadInterstitial()
        if self.interstitial .isReady {
            interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        }else{
            print("not yet" )
        }

    }

    func createAndLoadInterstitial()-> GADInterstitial{
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-6095430889174206/8832491082")
        interstitial.delegate = self

        //gadRequest.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
        interstitial.loadRequest(GADRequest())

        return interstitial

}
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/23827

Answer (score 1):

私はnendを使っていて，spritekitも使ったことがありません。なので，あまりわからないのですが，検索したところ，[こちら](http://iphone-app-developer.seesaa.net/article/399604929.html)のようなサイトがありました。内容がObjective-Cで申し訳ありません。